# FCM Push Notification token is not Generated

Tags: android, mysql, push-notification

I have create Project on firebase console site. Project is successfully created and download google-service.json file and paste in app on android studio. created class FirebaseInstanceIDService.java token generated in display logcat but it not generated and not display. when project run debug mode display FirebaseInstanceIDService.java is not load.

Android Studio tools - Firebase Assistant Cloud messaging setup Correctly display and connection also correctly display but token is not generated.

FirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
          super.onTokenRefresh();

        String newToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + newToken);

        Constan.token = newToken;
    }
}
```

Gradle.build(Project-level)

```
     dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
}
```

Gradle.build(app-level)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.firebase.zala.fiirebase">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You may be missing a step! Consider using Android Studio itself to add Firebase for you!

Answer (score 0):

The token will not be refreshed every time you run the app. So the function `onTokenRefresh` will rarely be called.

But it will surely be called the first time you run the app. So when it is obtained, you should save it in the shared preferences so that in next usages of the app, you can get the token from the shared preferences.

To get the token again, you can try uninstalling the app or clearing the app data, so that a new token will be generated and the method `onTokenRefresh` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) for FCM integration.

1) maven entry in build.gralde(project level)

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }// Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

uninstall you app from phone , and then again install and set your logcat to debug.  you'll get your token.